# How to restrict paste function after the maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to restrict paste function when it comes to maximum. For that I used the code

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.txtStyle', function (e) {
                debugger;
                var charsSoFar = $('#' + container_id).val().length;
                remaining = 500 - charsSoFar;
                $('#rem_' + container_id).text('Characters remaining ' + remaining);
                if (charsSoFar > 500) {
                    alert("Hai");
                }
            });
```

How can I restrict the Paste function? Please help

Comment: `on("paste keyup input",`

Comment: how about trying return false if(charSoFar >500) return false;

Comment: @Neha - the problem is, we can paste it first time

Comment: umm sorry to be confuse ..but its need to restrict on max, so first time if its char are more than 500 its not working?

Comment: @Neha - return false is worked,but it is blocking the paste function after pasting once

Comment: than i will suggest don't do return false @ cond substring the content to max length and set back to input. so user feel its not pasted :)

Comment: As my understanding you want to stop user input once its reach max, so i suggest if (textbox.val().length >500 ) textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(0,500)); . It will give illusion that after 500 char user can't input or paste in textbox.

Comment: @Neha- Thaks Neha.. its worked... :)

Comment: Good.  :-) I added it in ans please accept it if its helped/worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my understanding you want to stop user input once its reach max, so i suggest

```
if (textbox.val().length >500 ) 
   textbox.val(textbox.val().substring(0,500));
```

It will give illusion that after 500 char user can't input or paste in textbox.

Comment: how to restrict drag and drop from this textarea??

Comment: I am not sure which kind of drag drop but you can@ textare capture those event and and return false/ or make input cond as above.

Comment: sure !! give me link.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take look on this..... This will help you.

```
if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '118' || event.which == '86')) {
   alert('Paste Restricted!');
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6Gdkk/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.txtStyle', function(e) { debugger;
    var charsSoFar = $('#' + container_id).val().length;
    remaining = 500 - charsSoFar;
    $('#rem_' + container_id).text('Characters remaining ' + remaining);
    if (charsSoFar > 500) {
        if (e.keyCode == 86 && e.ctrlKey) {
            alert("Hai");
        }
    }
});
```